# Comparing elements of numpy arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, comparison, numpy

I want to compare two 1x3 arrays such as:

```
if output[x][y] != [150,25,75]
```

(`output` here is a 3x3x3 so `output[x][y]` is only a 1x3).

I'm getting an error that says:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
```

Does that mean I need to do it like:

```
if output[y][x][0] == 150 and output[y][x][1] == 25 and output[y][x][2] == 75:
```

or is there a cleaner way to do this?

I'm using Python v2.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should also get the message:

> Use a.any() or a.all()

This means that you can do the following:

```
if (output[x][y] != [150,25,75]).all():
```

That is because the comparison of 2 arrays or an array with a list results in a boolean array. Something like:

```
array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: I think .any makes more sense for `!=` and .all for `==`.

Answer (score 8):

The numpy way is to use [np.allclose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html#numpy-allclose):

```
np.allclose(a,b)
```

Though for integers,

```
not (a-b).any()
```

is quicker.

Answer (score 3):

convert to a list:

```
if list(output[x][y]) != [150,25,75]
```

Comment: You can also compare two arrays of the same shape, which gives you an array of True/False values.

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
a = output[x][y]
b = [150,25,75]

if not all([i == j for i,j in zip(a, b)]):
```